# Selection changed of datagrid does not changes the current row index

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

In my datagrid am changing the row selection based on some values.

```
 dgvGetData.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
```

but in the Datagrids selection changed event the current row index is not changed to the rowIndex.it is still the same before i set `dgvGetData.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;`

Comment: Is multiselect on because if I test it it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer
I set the code as the following

```
rowIndex = row.Index;
                        dgvGetData.ClearSelection();


                        dgvGetData.CurrentCell = dgvGetData.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2];
                        dgvGetData.CurrentRow.Selected = false;
                        dgvGetData.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
```

when i added the lines

```
gvGetData.CurrentCell = dgvGetData.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2];
                            dgvGetData.CurrentRow.Selected = false;
```

that worked and returned selected row index as current index..

Answer (score 0):

This usually works fine, only problem I can think of is having multiselect and getting back the previous selected row (that would be still selected). If this would be the problem, the fix would be easy:

```
myDataGridView.ClearSelection();
myDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Comment: the multiselect property is set to false and also i have alresdy added the code myDataGridView.ClearSelection(); before changing the selection

Comment: @SruthiSuresh I tested it on a new form and it works so idk where to go from here

Answer (score 0):

My Source code.
you miss cells[ColumnIndex ].

this code add.

```
DataGridView.Rows[ RowIndex ].Cells[ ColumnIndex ].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the property `SelectionMode` of your DataGridView-object `FullRowSelect`?

If you want to set the property programmatically.
Try this

```
dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Comment: yess i tried it by setting dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

Answer (score 0):

By using the following code you can find a value, which will be the selected row:

```
     int rowIndexResource = -1;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.resourceDataGridView.Rows)
    {
       if(row.Cells["resourceConfigId"].Value.ToString().Equals(resourceInfo.ResourceConfigId.ToString()))
       {
            rowIndexResource = row.Index;
           break;
        }
    }

this.resourceDataGridView.Rows[rowIndexResource].Selected = true;
this.resourceDataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowIndexResource;
this.resourceDataGridView.Focus();
```

"resourceConfigId" is the name of the column i the DataGridView and resourceInfo.ResourceConfigId.ToString() is the specific string value you are searching after in the grid. This is not an direct answer to your question, but you can consider if this still is useful.